# Angular 7 + Spring boot - Problema al hacer sorting en el server

Tags: angular7, angular-material

Estoy teniendo inconvenientes para hacer sorting con Angular 7 y la material table. Cuando clickeo en la mat-sort-header, dispara el evento y va al server y trae los resultados correctos. Por ejemplo, va al server con direction = asc y efectivamente el server responde con ese orden. El problema es que cuando vuelve del server al frontend angular, se resetea la vista y si vuelvo a clickear nuevamente en el encabezado vuelve a generar un sort con direction = asc en vez de desc. Se entiende?...siempre va con asc porque al volver del server la tabla es como que resetea todas las propiedades. Les dejo parte del codigo para ver si alguien ve algo incorrecto o quizas les pasó en algun momento.
home.component.html

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="datasource" *ngIf="datasource?.totalElements > 0" matSort (matSortChange)="sortData($event)">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="id" sticky>
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>#</mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let management">
            <a [routerLink]="" (click)="goToViewManagements(management)">{{management.id}}</a>
          </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="company" *ngIf="isSUPER_CLARO">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Empresa</mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell class="description-cell" *matCellDef="let management">{{management.company}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="lastname">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Apellido</mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell class="description-cell" *matCellDef="let management">{{management.lastname}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="firstname">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Nombre</mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell class="description-cell" *matCellDef="let management">{{management.firstname}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="dni">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Nro. DNI</mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell class="description-cell" *matCellDef="let management">{{management.dni}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="nim">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Nim</mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell class="description-cell" *matCellDef="let management">{{management.nim}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="state">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Estado</mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell class="description-cell" *matCellDef="let management">{{management.state}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="expirationpin"  *ngIf="isBOCC">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Expiración PIN</mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell class="description-cell" *matCellDef="let management">{{management.expirationpin}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
  ....

      </mat-table>
```

home.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
  ...
  this.datasource = new ManagementsDataSource(this.manService);
  this.datasource.loadManagements(this.authGuard.user['sub'], 0, 
        this.itemsPage,
        this.txtSearch, states.length > 0 ? states : null,
        this.fec_desde, this.fec_hasta, '', '');
  },
  error => {
    const eh: ErrorHandle = new ErrorHandle(this.router, this.errorService);
    eh.handleError(error);
  });
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  if (this.roleAuth) {
    this.paginator.page
        .pipe(
            tap(() => this.getManagements(true, this.sort.active, this.sort.direction)),
        )
        .subscribe();
  }
}

getManagements(paginador: boolean, active: string, direction: string) {
  ....
    this.datasource = new ManagementsDataSource(this.manService);
    this.datasource.loadManagements(this.authGuard.user['sub'],
      paginador ? this.paginator.pageIndex : 0,
      this.paginator.pageSize,
      this.txtSearch,
      states.length > 0 ? states : null,
      d1 ? d1 : null,
      d2 ? d2 : null, direction, active);
  ....
}

sortData(event) {
  this.getManagements(false, this.sort.active, this.sort.direction);
}
```

Espero me puedan ayudar. Intenté guardar en la storage los valores que tenia el MatSort y setearlos a la vuelta del server, pero no funcionó...es como que ignora esa parte. Gracias de antemano